# How to switch on default filters AND-ed together in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have the following Action Window definition

```
<field name="context">{
                'search_default_mine': 1,
                'search_default_current_year': 1,
   }</field>
```

This gives me back the results where I'm the contact person (mine) or that were created this year (current_year). I would like to have the results that are mine AND were created this year. Can this be done without defining a new filter in the search view?

Answer (score 2):

Solution is very simple just add

```
   <separator/>
```

beetwen filters

For example :

```
 <filter name="first_filter" string="Black Products"
    domain="[('is_black', '=', True)]"/>
        <separator/>
 <filter name="secund_filter" string="Red Products"
    domain="[('is_red', '=', True)]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a domain too:

```
<field name="domain">[('search_default_mine','=', 1), ('search_default_current_year', '=', 1)]</field>
```

I hope this can be helpful for you!